# Listen / Observe - changes in LocalStorage using store.js

Tags: javascript, html, events, local-storage

I am using [store.js](https://github.com/marcuswestin/store.js) (A JS library) to manage local storage.

**What I am trying to do**

Save value of `client` in `localStorage` in one tab of the browser and then when the value changes, I want to listen to the value changed.

**Problem**

The below code works in the same tab of the browser, but when I check another tab, there is no change event triggered.

```js
store.set('client', {
  'name': Math.random()
});

$('#mybtn1').click(function() {
  store.set('client', {
    'name': Math.random()
  });
});


store.observe('client', function(val, oldVal) {
  console.log('changed');
  console.log(store.get('client'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/marcuswestin/store.js/master/dist/store.everything.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="mybtn1" type="button">click</button>
```

**Help**

Can you please guide on what I am going wrong. I am also open to using Jquery for these changes listening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar issue with store.js so I end up using pure localStorage and event listener approach to implement the problem.

Here is the working JSFiddle: [Detect localStorage change on another browser tab](https://jsfiddle.net/m0vnhobd/3/)

Explanation:

This makes use of Web Storage API.

You can create new localStorage key-value pair using a call to,

```
localStorage.setItem("current_tenant", "Tenant1");
```

Now whenever this storage is changed, `StorageEvent` is fired. This event is only sent to other windows.

> The StorageEvent is fired whenever a change is made to the Storage object (note that this event is not fired for sessionStorage changes). This won't work on the same page that is making the changes — it is really a way for other pages on the domain using the storage to sync any changes that are made. Pages on other domains can't access the same storage objects. Source: [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API)

You can then add event listener on this storage and detect changes using event properties, `oldValue` and `newValue`
Eg,

Converted your example into [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m0vnhobd/11/) and here is the solution that combines both `storeJS` and `StorageEvent`

Comment: Your approach will trigger the change event for any changes in the local storage. I am looking for specific key changes. Example `client` value change.

Comment: Yes, that's true. You can filter out required keys by using "key" property of event